# Finding Last Row using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an inquiry on how to find the last row in excel vba. I am currently working on a project which requires me to find the last row of this particular worksheet called `Annex 1A`.

A snip image of the worksheet is shown below:

[image: Click Here For Image]

For instance, from the image above, `Row 32` and `Row 33` contain empty values and I would like to derive the total of rows that is being used.

I have tried this following method :

Method 1

```
LastRow = Sheets("Annex 1A").Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                  After:=Sheets("Annex 1A").Range("B1"), _
                  Lookat:=xlPart, _
                  LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                  MatchCase:=False).Row
```

Method 2

```
  LastRow = Sheets("Annex 1A").Range("B" & Sheets("Annex1A").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

The `LastRow` value would always return `31` instead of `33`. Is there any other way for me to derive the value of `33`?

Comment: [This article may answer your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Comment: @ForwardEd I have looked through this article for reference but it still doesnt get the value that I need :( but thanks for the suggestion !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method has worked for me in like 90% of the times I needed it:

```
Lastrow = Sheets("Annex 1A").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row
```

Comment: Thanks @gizlmeier! I have finally derived the 33 as a value by using ur method :) !

Answer (score 0):

I know you've already accepted an answer but this might be useful to others.

`UsedRange` is often eschewed as it can be unreliable. However, in this case it does have a place and may do the trick for you.

However, if you wish to regain full control of `UsedRange` then a method which combines `UsedRange` with some bespoke cell checking could be the answer. An example in your case, might be one which looks for a either a non empty cell or one that is shaded.

```
Public Function BespokeFindLastRow() As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    'Use the intersect function to find column B
    'as column references of UsedRange are relative
    'so if nothing is in column "A", then
    'column(1) or ("A") in your UsedRange would
    'actually be column "B".
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rng = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("B"))
    End With

    'Return -1 if no cells are found
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        BespokeFindLastRow = -1
        Exit Function
    End If

    'Loop backwards through the cells in the column range
    'to find either a non-empty cell or a coloured cell.
    For i = rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        With rng.Cells
            If Not IsEmpty(.Item(i)) Or .Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then
                BespokeFindLastRow = .Row
                Exit Function
            End If
        End With
    Next

    'Nothing was found in the column so return -1
    BespokeFindLastRow = -1
End Function
```

Comment: can this sub also be modified to get the lastRow without specifying the column? I like that code because it returns "0" if there is no value in the column.

Comment: @smartini, we tend not to answer extension questions within the same question, so that future people finding this question see a single question and answer. If you post a new question, I, or others, would be happy to answer though.