# Copy Specific Data to Another Closed Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to Excel VBA.

Kindly see the attach file.

I am having trouble upon a saving the specific data into another closed workbook.
Because every time I copy data and save it to a specific sheet(s) of the destination workbook, it will overwrite the existing data.

What I want is to continuously add the data every time i copied a a filtered data from listbox and send it to the destination workbook.

Honestly I only download this file and I want to used this as our records

```
Dim a, i As Byte, deg As String
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim sonsat, lastrow As Long, ara As Range
If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox3.Text = "" Then
MsgBox "Incomplete Data", vbCritical, ""
TextBox1.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If
lastrow = Sheets("liste").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
sonsat = Sheets("liste").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
           Set ara = Range("B2:B" & lastrow).Find(What:=TextBox1.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not ara Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "This name already exist ! Please try a different name", vbCritical, ""
        TextBox1.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
        End If
Cells(sonsat, 1) = sonsat - 1
Cells(sonsat, 2) = TextBox1
Cells(sonsat, 3) = TextBox2
Cells(sonsat, 4) = TextBox3
Cells(sonsat, 5) = TextBox4
Cells(sonsat, 6) = TextBox5
Cells(sonsat, 7) = TextBox6
Cells(sonsat, 8) = TextBox7
Cells(sonsat, 9) = TextBox8
Cells(sonsat, 10) = TextBox11
Cells(sonsat, 11) = TextBox12
Cells(sonsat, 12) = TextBox13
Cells(sonsat, 13) = TextBox14
Range("A" & sonsat & ":M" & sonsat).Font.ColorIndex = 11
MsgBox "Registration is successful", vbInformation, ""
Range("A" & sonsat & ":M" & sonsat).Interior.ColorIndex = 25
Call sort_id
Call text_boxes_clear
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton10_Click()

If ListBox1.ListCount = 0 Then
MsgBox "No items that will be copied.", vbCritical, ""
Exit Sub
End If
Call add_sheets

    If ComboBox1.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please Choose A WorkSheet From Drop-Down List ", vbInformation, ""
ComboBox1.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If
    Workbooks.Open (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Database.xls")
    Sheets(ComboBox1.Value).UsedRange.Cells.Clear
 Sheets(ComboBox1.Value).Range("A2:L" & ListBox1.ListCount + 1) = ListBox1.List
  Sheets(ComboBox1.Value).Columns.AutoFit

    ActiveWorkbook.Close True
MsgBox "The Listbox Records Were Copied.", vbInformation, ""

    ComboBox1.Clear
    ComboBox1.Enabled = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim sonsat, lastrow As Long, sor As String
If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox3.Text = "" Then
MsgBox "Item Is Not Selected To Change", vbCritical, ""
Exit Sub
End If
sor = MsgBox("Are your sure?", vbYesNo, "")
If sor = vbNo Then Exit Sub
lastrow = Sheets("liste").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("liste").Range("B2:B" & lastrow).Find(What:=ListBox1.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Activate
sonsat = ActiveCell.Row
Cells(sonsat, 2) = TextBox1
Cells(sonsat, 3) = TextBox2
Cells(sonsat, 4) = TextBox3
Cells(sonsat, 5) = TextBox4
Cells(sonsat, 6) = TextBox5
Cells(sonsat, 7) = TextBox6
Cells(sonsat, 8) = TextBox7
Cells(sonsat, 9) = TextBox8
Cells(sonsat, 10) = TextBox11
Cells(sonsat, 11) = TextBox12
Cells(sonsat, 12) = TextBox13
Cells(sonsat, 13) = TextBox14
Range("A" & sonsat & ":M" & sonsat).Font.ColorIndex = 11
MsgBox "Item Has Been Changed", vbInformation, ""
Call listbox_refresh
Call text_boxes_clear
ListBox1.Clear
CommandButton3.Enabled = False
CommandButton2.Enabled = False
CommandButton1.Enabled = True
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim cevap As String
If ListBox1.ListIndex >= 0 Then
    cevap = MsgBox("Entry will be deleted. ... Are you sure ?", vbYesNo, "")
If cevap = vbYes Then
lastrow = Sheets("liste").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
   Sheets("liste").Range("B2:B" & lastrow).Find(What:=ListBox1.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Activate
   Sheets("liste").Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Delete

End If
Else
MsgBox "Item Is Not Selected To Remove", vbCritical, ""
Exit Sub
End If
ListBox1.Clear
Call text_boxes_clear
Call sort_id
CommandButton2.Enabled = False
CommandButton3.Enabled = False
CommandButton1.Enabled = True
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
For a = 1 To 14
Controls("textbox" & a) = ""
Next
ListBox1.Clear
CommandButton1.Enabled = True
CommandButton2.Enabled = False
CommandButton3.Enabled = False
ComboBox1.Clear
ComboBox1.Enabled = False
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
For a = 1 To 14
Controls("textbox" & a) = ""
Next
Call CommandButton5_Click
UserForm2.Hide
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton7_Click()
Dim sat As Long
sat = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
ListBox1.List = Sheets("liste").Range("B2:M" & sat).Value
With ListBox1
        For i = 1 To 12
            deg = deg & CLng(Columns(i + 1).Width) & ";"
        Next i
        .ColumnWidths = deg
End With
ListBox1.ColumnCount = 12
TextBox10.Value = ListBox1.ListCount
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton8_Click()
ListBox1.Clear
Call text_boxes_clear
CommandButton1.Enabled = True
End Sub
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
Dim say, lastrow As Long
TextBox1 = ListBox1.Column(0)
TextBox2 = ListBox1.Column(1)
TextBox3 = ListBox1.Column(2)
TextBox4 = ListBox1.Column(3)
TextBox5 = ListBox1.Column(4)
TextBox6 = ListBox1.Column(5)
TextBox7 = ListBox1.Column(6)
TextBox8 = ListBox1.Column(7)
TextBox11 = ListBox1.Column(8)
TextBox12 = ListBox1.Column(9)
TextBox13 = ListBox1.Column(10)
TextBox14 = ListBox1.Column(11)
lastrow = Sheets("liste").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("liste").Range("B2:B" & lastrow).Find(What:=ListBox1.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Activate
say = ActiveCell.Row
Sheets("liste").Range("A" & say & ":M" & say).Select
CommandButton1.Enabled = False
CommandButton2.Enabled = True
CommandButton3.Enabled = True
End Sub
Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinDown()
On Error Resume Next
If ListBox1.ListIndex = ListBox1.ListCount - 1 Then Exit Sub
With Me.ListBox1
        .ListIndex = .ListIndex + 1
    End With
 End Sub
Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinUp()
On Error Resume Next
If ListBox1.ListIndex = 0 Then Exit Sub
With Me.ListBox1
        .ListIndex = .ListIndex - 1
    End With
    End Sub
Private Sub TextBox9_Change()
Dim k As Range, adrs As String, j As Byte, m As Long, myarr() As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'CommandButton1.Enabled = False
ReDim myarr(1 To 12, 1 To 1)
With Worksheets("liste")
ListBox1.Clear
ListBox1.ColumnCount = 12

    If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData
    If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
    Set k = .Range("C2:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row).Find(What:=TextBox9.Text & "*", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Else
    Set k = .Range("C2:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row).Find(What:="*" & TextBox9.Text & "*", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    End If
    If Not k Is Nothing Then
        adrs = k.Address
        Do
            m = m + 1
            ReDim Preserve myarr(1 To 12, 1 To m)
            For j = 1 To 12
                myarr(j, m) = .Cells(k.Row, j + 1).Value
            Next j
            Set k = .Range("C2:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row).FindNext(k)
        Loop While Not k Is Nothing And k.Address <> adrs
        ListBox1.Column = myarr
    End If
End With
With ListBox1
        For i = 1 To 12
            deg = deg & CLng(Columns(i + 1).Width) & ";"
        Next i
        .ColumnWidths = deg
End With
If TextBox9.Text = "" Then
ListBox1.Clear
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
TextBox10.Value = ListBox1.ListCount
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox9_Enter()
For a = 0 To 8
Controls("textbox" & a + 1) = ""
Next
TextBox10 = "0"
TextBox11 = ""
TextBox12 = ""
TextBox13 = ""
TextBox14 = ""
ListBox1.Clear
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim sonsat As Long
Sheets("liste").Activate
CommandButton2.Enabled = False
CommandButton3.Enabled = False
Me.Top = 40
Me.Left = 80
OptionButton1.Value = True
sonsat = Sheets("liste").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A" & sonsat & ":I" & sonsat).Interior.ColorIndex = 25
ComboBox1.Enabled = False
End Sub
Sub listbox_refresh()
Dim sat As Long
sat = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
ListBox1.List = Sheets("liste").Range("B2:M" & sat).Value
With ListBox1
        For i = 1 To 12
            deg = deg & CLng(Columns(i + 1).Width) & ";"
        Next i
        .ColumnWidths = deg
End With
ListBox1.ColumnCount = 12
'ListBox1.ListIndex = 0
End Sub
Sub text_boxes_clear()
For a = 1 To 14
Controls("textbox" & a) = ""
Next a
End Sub
Sub sort_id()
Dim k As Long
On Error Resume Next
For k = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Cells(k, 1).Value = k - 1
        Next k
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
Call CommandButton5_Click
End Sub
****'CODE OF THE MODULE****
Sub ac()
UserForm2.Show
End Sub
Sub add_sheets()
Dim m As Byte
Workbooks.Open (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Database.xls")
        For m = 1 To Sheets.Count
        UserForm2.ComboBox1.AddItem Sheets(m).Name
         Next m
    ActiveWorkbook.Close True
 UserForm2.ComboBox1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Comment: you need to prefix the cells with where they are going.  Workbook.Worksheet.Cells.  How are you planning on accessing the closed book are you opening it?

Comment: This link shows how to find the last used row. You can use this to populate cells from that row onwards http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37107504/finding-last-row-using-excel-vba

Comment: @JiminyCricket : this answer is better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920 or see the documentation : http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/918/methods-for-finding-the-last-used-row-or-column-in-a-worksheet#t=201701260930185488389

Comment: I don't plan to open the destination workbook, what i want is to paste the specific values i copy from the listbox/combobox and paste to a specific sheet of that destination closed workbook.  Please see the Code of the Module , here you can see that the sheets of the destination workbook is " Sub add_sheets() and uses For , Next Loop."  On the otherhand from the UserForm with the code                                 from "Private Sub CommandButton10_Click()"

Comment: Workbooks.Open (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Database.xls")
    Sheets(ComboBox1.Value).UsedRange.Cells.Clear
 Sheets(ComboBox1.Value).Range("A2:L" & ListBox1.ListCount + 1) = ListBox1.List
  Sheets(ComboBox1.Value).Columns.AutoFit                                                         Im having hard time for this code because once copied data it would reset or overwrite the previous data of the sheet of the destination workbook.